# Convert gRPC channel from C++ to Java

Tags: java-native-interface, grpc, grpc-java

I have a library, that already uses a [C++ version of gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc), and I need to implement a Java wrapper.
Thus, I need to use Java Native Interface (JNI) to convert `std::shared_ptr<grpc::Channel>` to [gRPC-Java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) `Channel`.

More specifically, I need to implement the following Java function:

```java
public native ManagedChannel CreateChannel(String address);
```

that references this existing C++ function:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<grpc::Channel> CreateChannel(std::string address);
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible? Yes. Easy? No.

The `Channel`/`ManagedChannel` API mainly has the `newCall()` method. Implementing that method would be annoying as you'd need to map `MethodDescriptor` and `CallOptions` to the C++ equivalents. But the bigger problem is it returns a `ClientCall` which would take more work to implement.

C++ uses a different API for flow control than Java, so you'd have to map those. The C++ callback API would be ideal in this situation, but it not currently available (time of writing: 2019 Q4). So that would mean creating threads and using the async API.

Comment: I had pretty the same question and it was clearly answered by Eric that they are incompatible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65389428/how-to-connect-to-grpc-c-inprocesschannel-not-from-c

Answer (score 2):

Very probably not. The Java implementation was not specifically designed to be interoperable with the C++ implementation, so it has its own pure Java `ManagedChannel` implementation.